# How to trace where packet is being dropped on the route?

Tags: networking, packet

I have a server address with both 443 and 80 ports open. I can connect to 80 just fine but 443 is being cut. I want to know where, at which point on the route, it is being dropped.

How can I get this trace?

Comment: There's no reliable way. Once upon a time, ICMP "Destination Unreachable" messages were designed to give you this information, but giving users (potential hackers) information about which firewall is dropping their packets is considered a leak of security information, so many routers and firewalls are configured to *not* send those messages, and many even filter out ICMP messages all together. So you could *try* watching for ICMP Destination Unreachable messages and maybe you'll get lucky, but probably not.

Comment: Yeah, problem is that only port 443 dropped, ping works just fine

Comment: If ping is working, `mtr` as in "My Traceroute" **might** be of help; available for Linux:en, not sure how it is with Windows. Check the man page and note options `u`,`T`, `S` and `P`.

Note though: port 443 is mostly used for secure web browsing ("https:" URLs); are you sure the server does this correctly?

Comment: Just to be clear, ICMP is used for much more than just ping. Ping is just ICMP "Echo" packets. I was talking about a different kind of ICMP messages: "Destination Unreachable".

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. @Hannu I can connect to port 80, but not 443, but proxy works fine with both.

Comment: The special thing with mtr is that it shows in which "hop" packet transmission is lost. Now, I'm not sure you can get a reasonable response from nodes using `mtr -P 443 ...` though.